# How can I disable close button in Thickbox IFRAME

Tags: javascript

There is close button in Thickbox I want to disable it by adding img above it in IFRAME (HTML) and I tried doing that but the image show behind the close button in Thickbox

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both elements have the same `z-index` and that the `image` is later in the code so it would be drawn over earlier elements. If that's not an option, you can force it to be drawn over by changing the `z-index`.

```
<img src="image.png" alt="">
<div>Some text</div>
```

CSS

```
div, img { position: absolute; } /* Draw them over each other */
div { z-index: 100; }
img { z-index: 101; }
```

Default is `0`, so setting `1` for the image alone should work.

Note that the `img`-tag is earlier in the code in this example.

Comment: Great but the problem is the first image in JavaScript and the sec image in HTML code show by IFRAME in the page, when I insert z-index the first image (js img) show behind all IFRAME so I do not want that. I just want it to show behind the first image?